# How to find the distance between sprites?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to check when the `worker` object comes closely to any of the `fence` objects in order to print a notification message. By "closely" I mean the distance of 20 pixels between the `worker` and the border of `fence`. For example, something like "distances_list = worker.get_dist(fences)", where "distances_list" would contain the current distances to all fences.

I could adopt the approach proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785931/how-to-find-the-distance-in-pixels-between-the-sprite-and-screen-corners), but maybe there is some built-in function for my task?

In `pygame` we can use different collision detection functions, but in the case described above there is no collision. Is there any built-in function to find the distance between the sprites?

```
import pygame, random
import sys

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210 ,210)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)

SCREENWIDTH=1000
SCREENHEIGHT=578

IMG_BACKGROUND = "background.jpg"
IMG_WORKER_RUNNING = "images/workers/worker_1.png"
IMG_WORKER_IDLE = "images/workers/worker_2.png"
IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT = "images/workers/accident.png"


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the background to be actually in the back
        self._layer = -1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        # let's resize the background image now and only once
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert(), (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



class GeoFenceInfluenceZone(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 0
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREY)
        self.rect = rect


class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = rect
        self.risk_level = risk_level
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)
        text = self.font.render(risk_level, 1, (255,0,0), GREEN)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(rect.width/2, rect.height/2))
        self.image.blit(text, text_rect)



class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # we introduce to possible states: RUNNING and IDLE
    RUNNING = 0
    IDLE = 1
    ACCIDENT = 2
    NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS = 0

    def __init__(self, image_running, image_idle, image_accident, location, *groups):

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 10)

        # each state has it's own image
        self.images = {
            Worker.RUNNING: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_running), (45, 45)),
            Worker.IDLE: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_idle), (20, 45)),
            Worker.ACCIDENT: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_accident), (40, 40))
        }

        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the workers on top
        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)

        # let's keep track of the state and how long we are in this state already            
        self.state = Worker.IDLE
        self.ticks_in_state = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.state]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.set_random_direction()


    def set_random_direction(self):
        # random new direction or standing still
        vec = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100,100), random.randint(-100,100)) if random.randint(0, 5) > 1 else pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

        # check the new vector and decide if we are running or fooling around
        length = vec.length()
        speed = sum(abs(int(v)) for v in vec.normalize() * self.speed) if length > 0 else 0

        if (length == 0 or speed == 0) and (self.state != Worker.ACCIDENT):
            new_state = Worker.IDLE
            self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        elif self.state != Worker.ACCIDENT:
            new_state = Worker.RUNNING
            self.direction = vec.normalize()
        else:
            new_state = Worker.ACCIDENT

        self.ticks_in_state = 0
        self.state = new_state

        # use the right image for the current state
        self.image = self.images[self.state]


    def update(self, screen):
        self.ticks_in_state += 1
        # the longer we are in a certain state, the more likely is we change direction
        if random.randint(0, self.ticks_in_state) > 70:
            self.set_random_direction()

        # now let's multiply our direction with our speed and move the rect
        vec = [int(v) for v in self.direction * self.speed]
        self.rect.move_ip(*vec)

        # if we're going outside the screen, change direction
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        # spritecollide returns a list of all sprites in the group that collide with
        # the given sprite, but if the sprite is in this group itself, we have
        # to ignore a collision with itself
        if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, building_materials, False) if s != self):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, machines, False) if s != self):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        # Risk handling
        self.handle_risks()

        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


    def handle_risks(self):
        for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False):
            if s != self:
                self.speed = 0
                self.state = Worker.ACCIDENT
                self.image = self.images[self.state]
                Worker.NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS += 1



class BuildingMaterials(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha(), (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



class Excavator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 3
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha(), (170, 170))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



image_cache = {}
def get_image(key):
    if not key in image_cache:
        image_cache[key] = pygame.image.load(key)
    return image_cache[key]


pygame.init()

# currently, one group would be enough
# but if you want to use some collision handling in the future
# it's best to group all sprites into special groups (no pun intended)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
building_materials = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences_infl_zones = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100), (700, 200)):
    Worker(IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE, IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT, pos, all_sprites, workers, building_materials, machines, fences)

# create multiple building material stocks
for pos in ((50,460),(50,500),(100,500),(850,30),(800,30)):
    BuildingMaterials("images/materials/building_blocks{}.png".format(random.randint(1,3)), pos, all_sprites, building_materials)

# create multiple geo-fences
risks = ["H","M","L"]
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40), pygame.Rect(450,370,68,48),
             pygame.Rect(0,0,20,SCREENHEIGHT),pygame.Rect(0,0,SCREENWIDTH,20),
             pygame.Rect(SCREENWIDTH-20,0,20,SCREENHEIGHT),pygame.Rect(0,SCREENHEIGHT-20,SCREENWIDTH,20)):
    risk = risks[random.randint(0,2)]
    GeoFence(rect, risk, all_sprites, fences)

# create influence zones for all geo-fences
for rect in (pygame.Rect(495,135,105,80), pygame.Rect(435,235,98,68), pygame.Rect(435,355,98,76)):
    GeoFenceInfluenceZone(rect, all_sprites, fences_infl_zones)

# and the background
Background(IMG_BACKGROUND, [0,0], all_sprites)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    all_sprites.update(screen)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: If you just want to know whether the worker is close to a fence or not but don't care about the actual distance, you could give your fences a second, bigger rect and use that for the collision detection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829496/6220679

Comment: If you need the distance, check out these solutions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978323/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-rectangles-context-a-game-in-lua 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453545/how-to-find-the-nearest-point-in-the-perimeter-of-a-rectangle-to-a-given-point 

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-a-point-and-an-axis-aligned-rectangle

Comment: @skrx: Thanks. I need the actual distance (20 px, 30 px, etc.). I checked these threads. In particular, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978323/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-rectangles-context-a-game-in-lua. In the top answer the function `rect_distance` is suggested. What I misunderstand is how to get the input parameters for this function in my particular case?

Comment: You need the `rect.topleft` and `rect.bottomright` coordinates and assign them to (x1, y1, x1b, y1b). I go swimming now, but I'll post an example later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178015/6220679) ported to pygame. The y-axis in pygame is flipped, so I had to swap the `top` and `bottom` variables and the distance can be calculated with `math.hypot`. You need to pass the `rect`s of the two sprites to `rect_distance` where they will be unpacked into the `x1, y1` (top left) and `x1b, y1b` (bottom right) variables. (You can see the distance in the window title.)

```
import math
import pygame as pg


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)


def rect_distance(rect1, rect2):
    x1, y1 = rect1.topleft
    x1b, y1b = rect1.bottomright
    x2, y2 = rect2.topleft
    x2b, y2b = rect2.bottomright
    left = x2b < x1
    right = x1b < x2
    top = y2b < y1
    bottom = y1b < y2
    if bottom and left:
        print('bottom left')
        return math.hypot(x2b-x1, y2-y1b)
    elif left and top:
        print('top left')
        return math.hypot(x2b-x1, y2b-y1)
    elif top and right:
        print('top right')
        return math.hypot(x2-x1b, y2b-y1)
    elif right and bottom:
        print('bottom right')
        return math.hypot(x2-x1b, y2-y1b)
    elif left:
        print('left')
        return x1 - x2b
    elif right:
        print('right')
        return x2 - x1b
    elif top:
        print('top')
        return y1 - y2b
    elif bottom:
        print('bottom')
        return y2 - y1b
    else:  # rectangles intersect
        print('intersection')
        return 0.


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((50, 80), all_sprites)
    player2 = Player((100, 200), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                player.rect.topleft = event.pos
                distance = rect_distance(player.rect, player2.rect)
                pg.display.set_caption(str(distance))

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, you could use for loops to iterate over the workers, but one of the itertools functions would be more efficient (I think you could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)).

Comment: I added the attribute `idf` to GeoFence init so that `fence` objects have identifiers. Then I wrote: `w_dist = {}
        for w in workers:
            f_dist = {}
            for f in fences:
                if f != self:
                    distance = self.rect_distance(w.rect, f.rect)
                    f_dist[f.idf] = distance
            w_dist[w.idw] = f_dist`. But I get the error `AttributeError: 'Worker' object has no attribute 'idf'`. I do not understand why `if f != self` does not work and `f` is `Worker` instead of `GeoFence`.

Comment: just to mention that I added this code to `update` function of `Worker`.

Comment: I think it would be better to post a new question, because I can't say much without seeing the code (a minimal example).